# Fastest way to check object key value type (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently trying to ensure that an object has keys set to specific value types. What is the fastest way to do so?

So far, I am doing something that seems inefficient through using multiple ifs

```
function bleh(obj){
  if(typeof obj.key1 != 'variableType')
    return false;
  if(typeof obj.key2 != 'variableOtherType')
    return false;
  // more repetition of ifs code with similar manner but with different keys
  return true;
}
```

Is there a faster way? Im not sure if this makes a difference, but im using angular and have jquery included. I would rather receive an answer that is vanilla js, but if there are built in functions or tricks with either jquery or angular it would be nice to know.

Comment: *"Is there a faster way?"* - Faster to write the code, or faster to execute?

Comment: I guess what I mean to say was "smarter" way

Comment: I really dont understand why people downvote. I put up a serious question that has not been asked before. I have supplied my code which puts up an example of what I am doing and I am asking for better solution. Using this site by the books and still haters persist..... ahh what to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In vanilla js I would do something like this:

```
var pairList = {
    key1: 'variableType1',
    key2: 'variableType2',
    // more pairs
};
var bleh = function(obj) {
    for (var pair in pairList) {
        var key = pair;
        var type = pairList[pair];
        if (typeof obj[key] != type) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Edited as per nnnnnn comments.

Comment: Should be `var type = pairList[pair];`. Also, you don't need the `key` variable.

Comment: could be, but I prefer in this way

Comment: When I said "should be", I meant "does not work unless you change it" - your current code never uses the values from `pairList`...

Comment: If you think that it doesn't work you don't know vanilla js, please check it :D

Comment: I'm not infallible, but I'm right about this. Again, your current code *never uses the values from `pairList`*.

Comment: please go and check [this resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: @nnnnnn I dont see why this code is wrong. pair takes up a property name (key1, key 2, etc) every iteration. Seems more than right to me